# Android custom drawable state not working

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a custom drawable state. I can see the state changing inside my custom view, however visually there is no colour change. Any help appreciated!

Here's my code:

**selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.test.myapplication">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/defaultt" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/error" app:my_state="1" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/success" app:my_state="2" />
</selector>
```

**error.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape
    android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="3dip" />
    <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#ff0000" />
    <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
</shape>
```

**attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyState">
        <attr name="my_state" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <com.example.test.myapplication.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**CustomView.java**

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    public static final int DEFAULT = 0;
    public static final int ERROR = 1;
    public static final int SUCCESS = 2;

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    private int state = DEFAULT;
    private static final int[] VALIDATION_STATE = new int[] { R.attr.my_state };

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        if( state == DEFAULT ) {
            return super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace);
        }

        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (state > 0) {
            Log.d("tag", "state is "+state);
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, VALIDATION_STATE);
        }
        return drawableState;
    }

    public void setState(int state) {
        this.state = state;
        refreshDrawableState();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private int mCurrentState = CustomView.DEFAULT;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mCurrentState != CustomView.ERROR) {
                    ((CustomView) findViewById(R.id.view)).setState(CustomView.ERROR);
                    mCurrentState = CustomView.ERROR;
                } else {
                    ((CustomView) findViewById(R.id.view)).setState(CustomView.SUCCESS);
                    mCurrentState = CustomView.SUCCESS;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Selector states must be either true or false. `app:my_state="1"` and `app:my_state="2"` both resolve to `app:my_state="true"`. Additionally, selectors should be ordered from most-specific to least-specific. Your first selector item matches all possible states.

Comment: thanks, that solved it! make this comment an answer so that I could select it. Can't believe I've wasted an hour on this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selector states should be defined as `boolean` attributes. You can place them directly inside a `<resources>` element -- you don't need to place them inside a `<styleable>` element.

res/attrs.xml:

```
<resources>
    ...
    <attr name="state_mystate" format="boolean" />
</resources>
```

When you reference the attribute from a selector `<item>`, a value of `true` means the state must exist within the current state set while a value of `false` means the state must *not* exist. If you don't include a state on the `<item>` the it doesn't matter whether it exists within the current state set.

When matching is performed on the selector, the items are matched in the order they are defined. If the first item has no states defined, as it does in your example, it will match all possible states and always be matched first. As a result, you should order your selector items as most-specific to least-specific.

The example below is for drawable, but it applies to all selectors (color, etc.).

res/drawable/my_selector.xml:

```
<selector>
    <!-- Matches only state sets that include app:state_mystate
         and don't include android:state_pressed. -->
    <item app:state_mystate="true"
          android:state_pressed="false" ... />

    <!-- Matches all state sets that include state_mystate. -->
    <item app:state_mystate="true" ... />

    <!-- Matches all possible states. -->
    <item ... />
</selector>
```